Как обратиться к struct в другом скрипте?
Как обратиться в другом скрипте и узнать сколько карт я уже записал в инспекторе?
Должно вывести число 2
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
[System.Serializable]
public struct MyData
{
    public string objectText;
    public Image imageOfUnit;
    public GameObject objectPrefab;
    public string objectId;
}
 
public class AllCardsData : MonoBehaviour
{
    
}


